# Ubuntu 18.04 Freeze frequently (mouse don't even move)

Tags: 18.04, mouse, freeze

Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, it freezes (where I can't even move my mouse at all) frequently.  It seems to happen at least once in a hour.       I quickly took a photo of the error that showed up when I opened my laptop.

[snap shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jK3S.jpg)

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot what causes it to freeze.   I suspect that this photo is one of few problems that my laptop is having with Ubuntu 18.04   Thanks.

Comment: TPM errors come from the `Trusted Computing Group's TPM hardware`... a chip on your motherboard. You can try turning off `secure boot` in your BIOS and see if that helps... or disable TPM... or install tpm* apps to diagnose a TPM problem.